# Fix Entity Framework inconsistent FK underscore

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ef-model-first

I'm fine with FK names of "Table_Id" **OR** "TableId" in my table. But the Entity Framework SQL generator is using both.

- Mapped associations (independent associations, FK properties visible): no underscore
- Constrained associations (foreign key associations): underscore

This kinda seems ridiculous - from a DB perspective there's no difference between these two relationships, so having consistency here would seem obvious. I'm building Model First.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some way to fix this?

---

EDIT:
By request, including a sample. I created a new Entity diagram and generated SQL. It validates. Here's a snapshot of the diagram and Generate Database from Model script. Note the BasketId on Apples vs. Basket_Id on Oranges. The only difference is having selected "Add foreign key properties to the 'Oranges' entity." when adding that association.

[image]

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, and Azure
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: 04/29/2013 23:38:07
-- Generated from EDMX file: C:\data\web-trunk\TestEntities.Data\TestEntities.edmx
-- --------------------------------------------------

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [TestEntities];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------


-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
-- --------------------------------------------------


-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'Baskets'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Baskets] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Apples'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Apples] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BasketId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Oranges'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Oranges] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Basket_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'Baskets'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Baskets]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Baskets]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'Apples'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Apples]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Apples]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'Oranges'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Oranges]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Oranges]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating foreign key on [Basket_Id] in table 'Oranges'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Oranges]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BasketOrange]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Basket_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Baskets]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_BasketOrange'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_BasketOrange]
ON [dbo].[Oranges]
    ([Basket_Id]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [BasketId] in table 'Apples'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Apples]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BasketApple]
    FOREIGN KEY ([BasketId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Baskets]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_BasketApple'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_BasketApple]
ON [dbo].[Apples]
    ([BasketId]);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Script has ended
-- ------------------------
```

---

Comment: I think you have wrong mapping , your TableId column is not mapped properly. That's why EF using the default one. Can you post your two entity classes and the mappings(if any) ?

Comment: done. let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here.. You can do the same thing for orange as well , to have `BasketId` in Orange as well.

Comment: The reproducability doesn't mean it's correct. Yes, I could change my models and expose FKs on all of them to hide what appears to be an inconsistency. I don't understand why the inconsistency is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there's no difference from a Data model perspective, but there is a difference from an Object Model perspective.

When you use Foreign Key Properties, then the Foreign key ID is included in the entity, but when you don't then the foreign key is silently used.  The naming is part of the Entity Framework "Convention over Configuration" policy.  EF sees a property named Basket_Id and doesn't see the property in the entity, so it knows to use this id without specifically configuring it.

By contrast, when Ef sees BasketId and sees the property in the entity, then it knows to map that field to the underlying BasketId column.

Basically, EF is distinguishing between the two types of foreign key navigation by using a naming convention.  You can read more about this here:

[Entity Framework Navigation Property generation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079863/entity-framework-navigation-property-generation-rules)

If you want to change this behavior, you could create a custom naming convention, remove the default one, and add your custom one that names things the way you want, however it very well could cause conflicts with the other type of navigation.

Honestly, I find it a bit ironic that you want to complain about consistency when you are being inconsistent in how you define your navigational properties.  Stick with one or the other if consistency is so important to you.

Comment: There's no irony. I had to materialize a pivot/mapping table to compensate for an EF deficiency, and reveal the FKs to mark them as a composite primary key. But thank you for the answer, the link especially explained the rationale. Side note, revealing an FK on some elements would be an inconsistency in the OM, not the DM.

Comment: BTW. The issue with inconsistency is my concern that the DM would break if I found I needed to reveal additional FKs in the future. Yeah, I care about consistency, but I care more about what/why/how stuff happens under the covers so I understand what to expect. Your closing comment was more adversarial than strictly necessary. I did ask if I was doing something wrong, after all.

Comment: @Shannon - I wasn't being adversarial, I was confused why you were concerned about consistency when you weren't being consistent yourself.  You can always use data attributes or fluent mapping to configure it to do whatever you want, so there's no danger of in anything "breaking".  I'd also argue that if you are so concerned about the data model then you should create the database in the manner you wish and use Database First instead.

Comment: Thanks clarifying. I did database-first on my last project, which probably explains where some of my criticality of the DM output comes from. But I was hoping to invest less effort into deployment/upgrade migrations for this project. It's probably a pipe dream anyway, because as far as I know Model-First Migrations still aren't available.