# What is EF Default Id Naming Convention Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF code first approach. I started to make mapping files(I come from nihbernate background) but found out that you really don't need them unless you need to do some changes.

I am wondering what will it use for the naming convention of my Id's?

Will it be `Product_Id` or `ProductId`?

**Edit**

Based on the comments so far this leaves me a bit puzzled. I was asking because I added 2 new classes(ie tables) and hooked them up and recreated my database.

Both of the FK in my tables that have a relationship to my  new tables all have "Product_Id" and I thought maybe it was because I had no mapping for it.

I just tried using mapping and same issue.

All other tables relationships have Camel Upper Case.

**Edit 2**

Hmm something funky is going on it has the same name twice in my table. Once it treats it as a FK and another time it treats it as just a regular column.

**Edit 3**

Figured it out, talking it out and posting here help me isolate the issue. The reason was because I was doing the poco way

```
public Product Product {get; set;}
   public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
```

I now release my ProductId I set as a type of int so what was happening was it would generate a column called ProductId in the db and then when it got time to make the FK it could not use ProductId anymore and had to use Product_Id

Comment: Use just `Id`. Why would you need a `Product` in property name, when it's already in the class name anyway?

Comment: The second one - ProductId. The EF will automatically use such field as Primary Key as well

Comment: The waters are starting to muddy. Do you perhaps need to compose another question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079863/entity-framework-navigation-property-generation-rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the `IdKeyDiscoveryConvention` is registered and according to its [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.idkeydiscoveryconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> Primary key detection is case insensitive. Recognized naming patterns are, in order of precedence:
>
> **'Id'**
>
> **[type name]Id**

Comment: "telling a bit different story": not really, it merely combines the `IdKeyDiscoveryConvention` and the [`StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.storegeneratedidentitykeyconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (seemingly lacking documentation) in a single paragraph.

Comment: True. but only in case the type is `Int16`, `Int32` or `Int64`.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. The fact that `Guid` has been dropped surprises me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use either `ProductId` or `Id` and it will be recognized as your primary key by Entity Framework's naming conventions.

You can also use the Key data annotation if you want to break convention.

```
[Key]
public int Product_Id {get;set;} //Note the underscore
```

You can also use the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(t => t.Product_Id); //Breaking convention again!
```