# DataContext selects fields which doesn't exist

Tags: c#, database, datacontext

I receive error

> {"Invalid column name 'Role_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'User_Id'."}

when I try to get all permissions like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Permission> GetAllPermissions()
{
        return base.DataContext.Permissions;
}
```

What are these "Role_id" and "User_id"??? They don't exist neither in my model nor in database... What does it mean? In my entire solutions I don't have anything like "Role_id" and "User_id"

This is query from DataContext (what are those "Role_id" and "User_id"...?):

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Role_Id] AS [Role_Id], 
[Extent1].[User_Id] AS [User_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Permissions] AS [Extent1]}
```

Permission model looks like :

```
public class Permission : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public Permission()
    {

    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedEventHandler != null)
        {
            propertyChangedEventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Table in database:

[image]

Context:

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set;}
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set;}
    public DbSet<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set;}
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set;}
    ...
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=my_Connection")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Those look like foreign keys

Comment: Do you have tables named `Role` and `User`, Where you might be referencing the Permissions `Id`?

Comment: Another question, which approach you are using codefirst, ModelFirst or DbFirst?

Comment: Yes I have classes: Role (Id, PermissionId), User (Id, Name, ... _no PermissionId_) and RolePermissions (Id, RoleId, PermissionId)

Comment: I took over the project when database and models were already created. Now I just modify according to the needs

Comment: Tables (Roles, Permissions, RolePermissions) are added to the database as well I created manually models

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so just wanted to make sure that you're not using Model first to generate your database from classes. 
The [autogenerated names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079863/entity-framework-navigation-property-generation-rules/11081568#11081568) comes from the conventions that EF uses. It simply track for basic [convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.103).aspx) of database e.g. Pattern `NameOfNavigationProperty_NameOfRelatedPK`.

In your case EF is trying to discover the Foreign keys by references and that's why you're getting generated values. This convention can be disabled via `DBModelBuilder`. 
In the DbContext you can apply following override and disable a convention named `NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention`

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    // ... goes other properties

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
    }
}
```

**Note:** *Make sure you test your application thoroughly. This fix doesn't guarantee that this will not affect other existing queries.*

Comment: Thank you. (I tried and it didn't change anything) I'm afraid I was wrong. I was working with ready database and I was not thinking what model is used. I edited my question, added MyContext.

Comment: It looks that I use model first

Comment: I know this the problem of Navigation property convention. Can you try turning off other [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions(v=vs.103).aspx) related to foreignkey and navigation properties. specially `AssociationInverseDiscoveryConvention` one.